# Why does migrated extension still show as not installed?

Tags: civievent, extension

I followed the instructions for [migrating my CiviCRM installation to another server](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/) as closely as I could. I can't figure out why one extension still shows as not installed?[image: If I click install again, I get errors about files already existing.]

If I click install again, I get errors about files already existing.

I have verified:

1. The extension's directory exists: [image]
2. The manifest file (info.xml) seems correct: [image]
3. The PHP files match those from the 'source' installation.

Does anyone have any trouble-shooting suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

My problem turned out to be incorrect entries on Resource URLS.

Answer (score 1):

In the list of extensions if you click the triangle on left to expand, it will say the full path where it thinks the extension is. Does that match up?

Another thing you can try is manually inserting a row the civicrm_extension table for it.

FYI the compatibility tag is the wrong format but that wouldn't make it appear uninstalled. (Should be

```
<compatibility>
  <ver>4.2</ver>
  <ver>4.7</ver>
  <ver>5</ver>
</compatibility>
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. My problem turned out to be incorrect entries on Resource URLS.